# Why did Euclid call 6 a perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history, perfect-numbers

The old Greek did not consider $1$ a number. Nevertheless Euclid called $6 = 1+2+3$ a perfect number. How could he use $1$ which was not a number?

Comment: The Greeks did not deny the fact that any number is divisible by $1$.

Comment: I think you're confusing with $0$, which indeed was not defined at the time.

Comment: $1$ is not a _prime_ number (I actually don't know what the classic Greek stance on that specific issue was), but it is very much a number, and a divisor of mostly anything.

Comment: Even if $1$ isn't considered a number, it can enter in a sum, can't it ?

Comment: Euclid had no problem with the notion of a unit.  Here, for example, is a reference on perfect numbers from the Elements:  http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIX/propIX36.html

Comment: @Arthur However, the ancient Greeks did not consider $1$ a number [at least, according to several historians of mathematics, I don't have own memories of that time]. A number was _what is composed of units_. Of course, in the long run it is more convenient to consider $1$ a number, so later $1$ was accepted into the realm of numbers.

Comment: I think you're confusing it with the old **Indians**, who did not consider **$0$** a number.

Comment: And I think that it was the Arabs who added "$0$" when they imported the Indian numerical system to the Middle East and from there to Europe.

Comment: @barakmanos you should review your history. Zero was invented by the Indians. Most of the contribution of the Arabs was algebra and what could be called algebraic geometry. All of the "Arabic" numerals are actually Indian. The Arabs of course knew this and gave due credit to the Indians, but they were first seen by Europeans in texts that were incompletely translated.

Comment: 1 was not considered a number, but it was considered a divisor: the definition of a perfect number talks about (proper) divisors, not about numbers.

Comment: Euclid foresaw [this scene](https://youtu.be/qmlqyPDLj24?t=1m19s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See :

- Thomas Heath, [A History of Greek Mathematics : Vol.I](https://books.google.it/books?id=J-kaAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA69) (1921), page 69 :

> Aristotle observes that the One is reasonably regarded as not being itself a number, because a measure is not the thing measured, but the measure or the One is the beginning (or principle) of number.

See also Euclid's [Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html#defs), Book VII, Defs.1&2 :

> 1. A *unit* is that by virtue of which each of the things that exist is called one.
> 2. A *number* is a multitude composed of units.

See also :

> 22. A *perfect number* is that which is equal to the sum its own parts.

and Def.3 :

> 3. A number is *a part* of a number, the less of the greater, when it measures the greater.

See Heath, page 74 :

> There is no trace [...] anywhere before Euclid, of the *perfect* number in the well-known sense of Euclid's definition (VII, Def.22), a number, namely, which is "equal to (the sum of) its own parts" (i.e. all its factors including $1$).

---

Probably, we see here an inconsistent terminology, due to the clash between the old [Pythagorean](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoreanism/) numerology, where the *numbers* are "individuals" with names and virtues, and a more modern approach, reflected into Euclidean arithmetical books.

Comment: So it seems that to Euclid, 1 is not a divisor (a "part") since it is not a number (but a unit)? -- oh, I guess 1 must itself be a number then (being the sum of a single unit), although that is not a multitude ... I'm confused!